# Implementar comunicação por voz e vídeo chamada no android?

Tags: android, streaming

Queria saber o que começar a estudar para implementar funcionalidades como vídeo chamada e chamada por voz no android. Quais bibliotecas estudar e tals.
Me dêem um norte.
:)

Comment: Protocolo Voip.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só para esclarecer o comentário do @mauhumor, VOIP não é um protocolo, VOIP é uma tecnologia IP que define a capacidade de transmissão de VOZ sobre IP, geralmente usamos como transporte de dados o protocolo `UDP`, este protocolo não é confiável, ou seja ele não possui nenhum mecanismo de controle e retransmissão de dados, isso quer dizer que se um determinado pacote se perder ele não será retransmitido e realmente ele é a melhor escolha, quando falamos em transmissões em tempo real e que algumas perdas de dados não afetam tanto a comunicação ele é a escolha óbvia, pois ele não vai adicionar latência durante uma transmissão tentando retransmitir pacotes como é feito no protocolo `TCP`.

Pois Bem agora que você sabe qual protocolo usar para comunicação stream, existem alguns protocolos de sinalização de chamadas por voz, essa sinalização nada mais é do que uma conversa entre o ponto `A` e o ponto `B` que define quando uma ligação foi recebida do ponto `A` para fazer o ponto `B` tocar, se o ponto `A` e `B` ainda estão em uma chamada ativa, se um dos pontos desligou para poder encerrar os sockets, etc, etc, etc... O protocolo de sinalização mais atual e mais utilizado hoje em dia é o `SIP` mas você também pode encontrar o `H323` e o `IAX` ou seja é só a sinalização de controle sobre o curso da chamada. O transporte da mídia em sí será feito em outro protocolo que ficará responsável pela transmissão da mídia (voz ou video), hoje em dia é muito comum o protocolo `RTP - (Real-time Transport Protocol)`.

Essa explicação acima define uma excelente arquitetura para transmissão de voz ou vídeo, e isso com certeza é implementado em transmissões de grande escala (whats, skype, etc). Agora se você quer apenas aprender o básico, fazer de brincadeira uma transmissão de voz sobre IP do seu computador ou Smartphone para outra pessoa, você pode abrir seu microfone, capturar a voz, enviar os pacotes de VOZ dentro de um socket UDP, do outro lado sua outra aplicação vai receber os pacotes UDPs e dar play no áudio recebido para poder escutar, pronto você está fazendo uma transmissão de áudio em tempo real sobre IP.

Isso é o básico do básico, se quiser ir a fundo nisso você tem que comer com farinha, sockets, DSP, compactação de dados (diminuir os dados enviados para economizar banda), arquitetura IP.

Como você deve estar percebendo o assunto é amplo de mais para entrar em todos os campos citados acima, espero que pelo menos ajude a você entender e saber por qual caminho seguir.

PS: eu não conheço nenhuma biblioteca pronta para fazer isso em android, se você pensar friamente é preciso de algum servidor ou algum método que reúna e atualize a informação dos ips dos clients, é claro você precisa conhecer em qual IP o cliente Y está para poder chamá-lo.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria, muito obrigado.